# I have an expression for get property name. I want string of hole Expression as it is

Tags: c#-4.0

```
<ReflectionTest>(x => x.ReflectionTestHelperClass1.ReflectionTestHelperClass2.InnerField)
```

When I am passing this expression, I want return `"ReflectionTestHelperClass1.ReflectionTestHelperClass2.InnerField"` as a string.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Could you share more of the surrounding code context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(x => x.ReflectionTestHelperClass1.ReflectionTestHelperClass2.InnerField), this is Expression type you can use this expression to get string as you required.

```
public string GetExpresionBody(Expression expression)
{
var memberExpression = expression as MemberExpression;

if (memberExpression == null)
return string.Empty;

if (memberExpression.NodeType == ExpressionType.Parameter)
return string.Empty;

var classValue = GetExpresionBody(memberExpression.Expression);
var result = classValue + (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(classValue) ? "" : ".") + memberExpression.Member.Name;

return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
private static string GetExpresion(Expression expression)
{
var memberExpression = expression as MemberExpression;

if (memberExpression == null)
return string.Empty;

if (memberExpression.NodeType == ExpressionType.Parameter)
return string.Empty;

var result = GetExpresion(memberExpression.Expression) + memberExpression.Member.Name;

// remove '.' from result which is comes first

return result;
}
```

Comment: i want '.' between memners